# How to reduce code for bootstrap grid system?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class, tags

I'm writing some code with bootstrap and i often use `"container-fluid col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-s-3 col-xs-3"` or `"container-fluid col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-s-6 col-xs-6"`. I was wondering if there was a way to reduce the code i write and not write these lines multiple times.

Thanks

Comment: You should only use the smallest as all of them are the same number. " container-fluid col-xs3" will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-s-3 col-xs-3` is actually same as using only `col-xs-3`

The best way to think about the grid classes is that they work from mobile up. This means by default your grid will stack from mobile up until the grid class breakpoint you’ve used is reached.

For example, using `.col-lg-4` means your grid will stay stacked on mobile, tablet, and small desktop screens. Only until the large desktop breakpoint is reached will the grid go horizontal.

Side notes:

`col-s-3` should be `col-sm-3`.

`container-fluid` is a container class and should not be with the column classes

General structure should be something like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xx-x">
            Column
         </div>
         <div class="col-xx-x">
            Column
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        ...
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for so many classes if width is gonna be three colunms on all screen sizes. It is enough to start from smallest screens col-xs-3 and width will be the same on all breakpoints. Another thing don't use column classes with container clases. Bootstrap structure goes first container then row and then columns.